# toggle display with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, display

```html
<!-- This is the main div -->
<div class="main-cont">
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont first"><p>Matrix Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont second"><p>Vector Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Trignometric</span> Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont fourth"><p>Integration&<br>Differentiation</p></div></a>
</div>
<!-- This is the first div -->
<div class="hidden">
  <h2 class="matrix">Matrix Calculations</h2>
  <div class="main-cont">
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third matrix"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- This is second div -->
<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Vector Calculations</h2>
  <div class="main-cont">
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- This is third div -->
<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Trigonometric Calculations</h2>
  <div class="main-cont">
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- This is fourth div -->
<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Calculus Calculations</h2>
  <div class="main-cont">
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

by using css `display:none;` initially I have hidden the four divs.I want to display the first hidden div if the div with class first of the main div is clicked the first hidden div must be displayed and the others should remain hidden. And if the div with class second of the main div is clicked the second hidden div must be displayed and ther others should remain hidden. and it is the same with the other hidden divs.
I tried using the javascript code. but the hidden divs are displayed only for a second and again they disappear.
please provide a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, You does not need any anchor tag to achieve this.

> Just use this little js and wrap all the sub contents under single parent

```js
const link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
const subcontent_children = Array.from(document.getElementById('sub-contents').children);

link.forEach(link=>{
  link.onclick = function(){
    const sub_cont_id = this.classList[1];
   subcontent_children.forEach(c=>{
      c.classList.toggle('show',c.id == sub_cont_id);
   }); 
    
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
p{
margin:0;
}
.link{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:5px;
}

.link:hover{
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
        <div class="link first"><p>Matrix Calculations</p></div>
       <div class="link second"><p>Vector Calculations</p></div>
       <div class="link third"><p><span>Trignometric</span> Calculations</p></div>
        <div class="link fourth"><p>Integration&<br>Differentiation</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id='sub-contents'> <!-- wrap all the sub in one parnet -->
      <div class="hidden" id='first'>
        <h2 class="matrix">Matrix Calculations</h2>
        <div class="main-cont">
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third matrix"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont matrix"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id='second'>
        <h2>Vector Calculations</h2>
        <div class="main-cont">
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id='third'>
        <h2>Trigonometric Calculations</h2>
        <div class="main-cont">
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id='fourth'>
        <h2>Calculus Calculations</h2>
        <div class="main-cont">
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Basic <br>Calculations</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Determinant<br>of matrix</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont third"><p><span>Inverse&</span><br>Transposition</p></div></a>
        <a href=""><div class="sub-cont"><p>Eigen values&<br>Vectors</p></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```